# Ranges in Kotlin below API 21

Tags: android, kotlin, android-api-levels

I want to store key-value pairs like `< 4.1, 29..35 >` which I can do with a `HashMap<Double, Range<Int>>`:

```
val womanMap: HashMap<Double, Range<Int>> = hashMapOf()

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
fun createMap() {
    //This both requires API 21
    val range = Range(29,35)
    womanMap[4.6] = Range.create(29,35)
}
```

How can I do this below API level 21?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/) instead:

```
val womanMap: HashMap<Double, IntRange> = hashMapOf()

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    fun createMap() {
        val range = 29..35
        womanMap[4.6] = 29..35
    }
```

Note that `29..35` is a **closed** interval:

```
for (a in 29..35) print("$a ") // >>> 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
```

To create a range which does not include its end element use `29 until 35`:

```
for (a in 29 until 35) print("$a ") // >>> 29 30 31 32 33 34
```

*For more info: [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)*

Answer (score 5):

[`Range`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Range.html) is a class in the Android SDK, this is tied to API 21. You could use [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/) provided by the Kotlin standard library instead though.

You can find usage examples for Kotlin ranges [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html).

Here's what their basic usage looks like:

```
val range = 1..10    // creation
println(range.first) // 1
println(range.last)  // 10
println(5 in range)  // true
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help!!